# What is this icon in taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have just had trouble with my Windows 7 laptop getting stuck for hours installing updates.  After a few boots into safe mode boots it is now all ok again, but I noticed a strange icon appeared in the taskbar for a few hours, it has now gone.

Can anyone help identify what it might be?

[image]

Comment: Right click on the icon and see what options it provides. This might give us a clue on what it really could be. Notification icons can be from 3rd party applications, so we really cannot say just by looking at it

Comment: This icon appeared after installing any software ?

Comment: Well, it’s not a Windows icon, that’s for sure. // What hardware is this? Please provide make and model. Also, what wireless hardware does this laptop feature?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's Avast Secureline icon. X telling that it's VPN is not on.

You should see what it is by hovering your mouse over that icon.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can figure out the purpose of an tray icon by clicking it. I'd start with a mouse-over for any tool tips, then a right mouse click (which usually gives you a menu), then click and finally double click.

Comment: Are you sure this will work? Because it doesn’t. You get the window that contains all tray icons – which is of course owned by Explorer.

Comment: My test condition led to a faulty assumption of processes directly drawing the icons. Removed the non-working part of my answer.